# Category type for Observation/Forecast/Diagnostic/Analysis

Tags: terminology, programming

I'm trying to build an application that searches archived weather data.  I need a category term for which the values can be any of the following:

- Observation
- Forecast
- Analysis
- Diagnostic

The best we've come up with is analysisType.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing identifier names in a computer program, something we specifically disallow.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reword the question, but I don't agree that it is really off-topic.  Yes, it is specifically about choosing a term for a computer program, but the words are related.  I'm just looking for a better relation for the words than the ones I had thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider "reportType" instead just to avoid the somewhat awkward "analysisType = analysis" scenario. There's nothing stylistically wrong with saying analysisType though. It just might be confusing if your 'analysis' variable is actually an object itself down the road.

Comment: Thanks.  It just never occurred to me that these are really different kinds of reports.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, each of these terms describe different methodological approaches for studying weather systems.

> **Method:**
>
> - Observation
> - Forecast
> - Analysis
> - Diagnostic

Or, **"Study Type"** perhaps.